# Indeterministic sets in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, set, non-deterministic

#### Python 2

Sets are collections of unordered values. If I construct a set via a set literal, e.g.

```
s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

and then print it, I get the elements in some scrambled order. However, it seems that in Python 2.7, the above example always results in the same ordering:

```
print(s)  # set(['a', 'c', 'b']) in Python 2.7
```

How does Python 2.7 decide on this ordering? Even the hashes of `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` are not in the order produced.

#### Python 3

In Python 3.x (including 3.6 where `dict` keys are ordered) the resulting order seems to be random, though always the same within a given Python process. That is, repeatedly re-building the set literal always lead to the same ordering, as long as I do not restart the Python interpreter.

To check the ordering across multiple Python processes, consider the bash code

```
(for _ in {1..50}; do python3 -c "s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; print(s)"; done) | sort -u
```

This will (most often) show the 6 different ways the 3 elements can be arranged. Switching out `python3` with `python`(2), we only see the ordering `['a', 'c', 'b']`. What determines the ordering in Python 3?

I see that the `hash` value of objects are deterministic in Python 2 while random (though constant within a Python process) in Python 3. I'm sure this is key to the full explanation.

#### Edit

As deceze writes in his comment, I would like to know if Python explicitly does something just to achieve this randomization, or if it happens "for free".

Comment: What's the point? You are not supposed to rely on a particular ordering of sets or dicts. If you need that, you should use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Also the hash behaviour you discovered is consistent with the properties it should have a hash function. If you need a deterministic hash, implement your own.

Comment: It's expected that there will be *some* order in a deterministic algorithm, unless Python is going out of its way to deliberately *randomise* the order.

Comment: While the complete hash values of these chars are not in that order, their lower bits are! For small hash-based containers python only uses those lower bits.

Comment: @Wombatz Thanks, that's a pretty big piece to the puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the difference in Python 3 (from Python 3.3 onwards) is that hash randomization is enabled by default, you could turn this off by setting the [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) environmental variable to a fixed value:

```
$ export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
$ (for _ in {1..50}; do python3  -c "s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; print(s)"; done) | sort -u
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Equally you can turn hash randomization on in Python 2 with the [`-R` flag](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R):

```
$ (for _ in {1..50}; do python2 -R -c "s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; print(s)"; done) | sort -u
set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
set(['b', 'c', 'a'])
set(['c', 'b', 'a'])
```

Note, you don't generally want to turn it off since having hash randomization enabled helps protect against certain denial-of-service attacks.

Comment: Just remember to tun it back on :). Nice +1!

Comment: The main reason I would want to turn it off is that when writing monte-carlo simulations, I always print out the value of the random.seed and provide a means to specify the seed when running the code. That way, if something funny happens during a simulation (bug or interesting behavior), I can rerun the exact same trajectory with, say, more output to investigate.