# what is deciding the order of the set elements in this python 3 code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-3.6

Why is the order of the elements being changed only when it goes through the function call? what is deciding this order?

```
# test_set_order.py
def unpack(input):
    print('input is {}'.format(input))
    result = []
    for i in input:
        result.extend(i)
    return result

print(unpack({'A', 'B'}))
```

Executing the script above results in different outputs:

```
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'B', 'A'}
['B', 'A']
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'B', 'A'}
['B', 'A']
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'A', 'B'}
['A', 'B']
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'B', 'A'}
['B', 'A']
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'A', 'B'}
['A', 'B']
$ python test_set_order.py
input is {'A', 'B'}
['A', 'B']
```

This is on `python 3.6.5`. On python `2.7.13` you **always get the same order**

It seems that order only gets changed after the function call. It doesn't happen before:

```
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print(bla)
{'A', 'B'}
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print(bla)
{'A', 'B'}
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print(bla)
{'A', 'B'}
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print(bla)
{'A', 'B'}
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print([i for i in bla])
['A', 'B']
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print([i for i in bla])
['A', 'B']
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print([i for i in bla])
['A', 'B']
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print([i for i in bla])
['A', 'B']
>>> bla = {'A','B'}; print([i for i in bla])
['A', 'B']
```

**UPDATE:**

seems that it has to do with the hashing and it is decided when the interpreter starts. This is enough to reproduce:

```
$ python -c "print({'A', 'B'})"
{'B', 'A'}
$ python -c "print({'A', 'B'})"
{'A', 'B'}
```

the value of `'A'.__hash__())` changes each time on `python 3`

Comment: The hashing determines the order but these are undocumented and not guaranteed implementation details, don't use a set if you want a particular order

Comment: @Chris_Rands this is not the same question as the one you linked. Why does the order change only during the function call? and not in the other examples

Comment: See my 2nd dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896202/indeterministic-sets-in-python-2-and-3, the reason is that hash randomization is enabled by default in Python 3, you can switch it off via `PYTHONHASHSEED`

Comment: Cool, thanks! that one is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered in Python. You should not expect consistency.

For a simple example, at the REPL for Python3 (`python -i`),

```
>> x={3,1,2}
>>> print(x)
{1, 2, 3}
```

And similarly with Python2

```
>>> x={3,2,1}
>>> print(x)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Nor are they simply autosorted, as in this Python3 example:

```
>>> x={3,('a','b'), 'x',0.11,'y',None, 'z',4.11,('c','d')}
>>> print(x)
{0.11, 3, 'y', 4.11, ('c', 'd'), 'x', ('a', 'b'), None, 'z'}
```

If you want them to stay in the inserted order, use an `OrderedSet` like [this](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) or just  reuse `OrderedDict`.

Comment: `OrderedSet` isn't a thing in the standard library though

Comment: Clarification added

Answer (score 0):

Because  [by definition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) a set is an unordered pair. If you want them ordered use a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Just replace:

```
{'A', 'B'}
```

with:

```
['A', 'B']
```

This is because sets are created using curly braces `{}` and lists are defined using brackets `[]`